# USB communication between Android 2.1 phone and Windows 7 PC

Tags: android, usb

Is there a way to send data from an Android 2.1 phone to a Windows 7 PC via USB? I have found the Android USB API but it is not supported by Android 2.1.  I can send data from the PC, but I do not know how to do this on the mobile side.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to read through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html), the developer site.

Android supports USB Host Mode on API 12 and up (3.1 Honeycomb).

Android supports USB Accessory Mode on API 10 and up (2.3.4 Gingerbread).

The difference in host versus accessory mode is which device provides the power. I am not sure which one you wanted to use, but if the Android is the host (Host Mode) then it will provide power to the computer (probably not what you want). In accessory mode, the Android will draw power from the computer.

Unfortanetly, I don't think you will be able to do this on 2.1 at all.

Comment: Also, if you are looking to use Host Mode then you will need a device that has the hardware to support that since not all of them do, as well as an OTG cable/adapter inorder to tell the device to go into Host Mode.

Comment: Is driver too is necessory for detecting usb devices?